# how to implement firebase emulator suite on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-tools

I have a project where we use firebase as a backend server, I wanted to connect to firebase emulator suite so that whenever I test something, I use the local data so that I don't impact the production database, I did the implementation by adding this code to a method where I call it in every activity

```
    fun setupEmulator() {
        // Use emulators only in debug builds
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk_")) {
            try {
                Log.d("emulator_status", "emulator for database and auth has started")
                Firebase.database.useEmulator(Const.EMULATOR_HOST, Const.DATABASE_EMULATOR_PORT)
                Firebase.auth.useEmulator(Const.EMULATOR_HOST, Const.AUTH_EMULATOR_PORT)
                Firebase.storage.useEmulator(Const.EMULATOR_HOST, Const.STORAGE_EMULATOR_PORT)
                Log.d("emulator_status", "Database URL: ${Firebase.database.reference}")
                Log.d("emulator_status", "Emulator UI URL: http://localhost:4000")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("emulator_status", e.message.toString())
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(
                "emulator_status",
                "Emulator is not working, this version might be a release version or it's a physical device"
            )
        }
    }
```

this method works perfectly at the beginning, but after going to a different fragment, it uses the production database again, how can I unify the usage of the firebase emulator suite where I can initialize it once and will be used all the time in debug builds

Comment: You should probably show **all** of the relevant code here that doesn't work the way you expect, not just the code that sets up the emulator.  You could be doing something wrong in other code, and we just can't see.  You should explain in the question the steps you are taking that reproduces the unexpected behavior so that we can do the same.

Comment: @DougStevenson the reason I didn't add other the other code is because it's just a normal call in a repository or a viewmodel, give me exactly what is missing and i will show it to you

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase` is implemented as a singleton, so calling Firebase.database gets you the same instance each time. However, calling useEmulator after making some database calls will throw an error. Is this what you're seeing?
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/e189eed5e19eb1ef3d7446922dc2837e25024eae/firebase-database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.java#L39

Comment: @Chris I suppressed the error of the instance, but if it's the same instance, why is it going back to production?

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? It looks to me like you're trying to connect to the emulators twice, which is causing the issue. Are you seeing data change in prod?

Comment: @Chris i tried setting it up for activities only (since they manage the fragment cycle), the error says that it is already initialized, but when i don't call it in the new started activity it show updates the production data